# How to make the custom parser for text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Actually I set four columns using data table and I want this column retrieve value from text file. I used regex for remove the particular line from the text file.

My objective is that I want to show text file on the grid using data table so first I am trying to create data table and remove the line (show at the program) using regex.

Here I post my full code.

```
namespace class
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            StreamReader sreader = File.OpenText(@"C:\FareSearchRegex.txt");
            string line;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr;
            dt.Columns.Add("PTC");
            dt.Columns.Add("CUR");
            dt.Columns.Add("TAX");
            dt.Columns.Add("FARE BASIS");
            while ((line = sreader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var pattern = "---------- RECOMMENDATION 1 OF 3 IN GROUP 1 (USD 168.90)----------";
                var result = Regex.Replace(line,pattern," ");
                dt.Rows.Add(line);    
            }
        }
    }

    class Class1
    {
        string PTC;
        string CUR;
        float TAX;

        public string gsPTC
        {
            get{ return PTC; }
            set{ PTC = value; }
        }

        public string gsCUR
        {
            get{ return CUR; }
            set{ CUR = value; }
        }

        public float gsTAX
        {
            get{ return TAX; }
            set{ TAX = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your input source?

Comment: Why regex for a _literal_ match? Is your input a CSV file? Can't you use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`?

Comment: @Cylian, Please see this link, http://pastebin.com/gGm3id5F

Comment: What is `Class1 obj = new Class1();`?

Comment: @Adriano, this is text file. Please check pastebin.com/gGm3id5F. this is contain my input file.

Comment: @Tim, Please ignore this line.

Comment: How fields are separated? just spaces or tabs? Can you _search_ the file (ignoring all lines) until you get the header? `PTC    CUR   TAX   FARE BASIS`?

Answer (score 0):

If your format is strict(e.g. always 4 columns) and you want to remove only this complete line i don't see any reason to use regex:

```
var rows = File.ReadLines(@"C:\FareSearchRegex.txt")
    .Where(l => l != "---------- RECOMMENDATION 1 OF 3 IN GROUP 1 (USD 168.90)----------")
    .Select(l => new { line = l, items = l.Split(','), row = dt.Rows.Add() });
foreach (var x in rows)
    x.row.ItemArray = x.items;
```

(assumed that the fields are separated by comma)

**Edit**: This works with your pastebin:

```
string header = "  PTC       CUR                 TAX           FARE BASIS";
bool takeNextLine = false;
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\FareSearchRegex.txt"))
{
    if (line.StartsWith(header))
        takeNextLine = true;
    else if (takeNextLine)
    {
        var tokens = line.Split(new[] { @"   " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        dt.Rows.Add().ItemArray = tokens.Where((t, i) => i != 2).ToArray();
        takeNextLine = false;
    }
}
```

(since you have an empty column which you want to exclude from the result i've used the clumsy and possibly error-prone(?) query `Where((t, i) => i != 2)`)

Comment: Thanks Tim. It is working. If possible can you tell me, how to this o/p display on grid view.

Comment: @user88: Edited my answer to take your sample file into account. To display it in a GridView just use the `DataTable` as DataSource and DataBind it (autogeneratecolumns=true).

Comment: If i want all lines except this "---------- RECOMMENDATION 1 OF 3 IN GROUP 1 (USD 168.90)----------".

Comment: @user88: Your first comment was "It is working", what has happened that it's not working anymore? If you're referring to my second approach according to your posted pastebin file, i don't see how you want to use a line as(from your file) `">> FXS3 TO SELECT  >> FXZ3 TO BOOK  >> FXU3 TO BOOK AND CREATE TST"` to create a `DataRow` with your 4 columns.

Comment: I am using your second approach. It's working fine but I want remove only this line "---------- RECOMMENDATION 1 OF 3 IN GROUP 1 (USD 168.90)----------". If my o/p are not display with coloumn , It's ok.

Comment: @user88: You're welcom, if it helped consider to accpe it :)

Answer (score 0):

To parse the file you'll need to:

1. Split the text of the file into data chunks. A chunk, in your case can be identified by the header `PTC       CUR                 TAX           FARE BASIS` and by the `TOTAL` line. To split the text you'll need to tokenize the input as follows> (i) define a regular expression to match the headers, (ii) define a regular expression to match the `Total` lines (footers); Using (i) and (ii) you can join them by the order of appearance index and determine the total size of each chunk (see the line with `(x,y)=>new{StartIndex = x.Match.Index, EndIndex = y.Match.Index + y.Match.Length})` below). Use `String.Substring` method to separate the chunks.
2. Extract the data from each individual chunk. Knowing that data is split by lines you just have to iterate through all lines in a chunk (ignoring header and footer) and process each line.

This code should help:

```
string file = @"C:\FareSearchRegex.txt";
string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
var headerRegex = new Regex(@"^(\)>)?\s+PTC\s+CUR\s+TAX\s+FARE BASIS$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
var totalRegex = new Regex(@"^\s+TOTAL[\w\s.]+?$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
var lineRegex = new Regex(@"^(?<Num>\d+)?\s+(?<PTC>[A-Z]+)\s+\d+\s(?<Cur>[A-Z]{3})\s+[\d.]+\s+(?<Tax>[\d.]+)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
var dataIndices = 
    headerRegex.Matches(text).Cast<Match>()
        .Select((m, index) => new{ Index = index, Match = m })
        .Join(totalRegex.Matches(text).Cast<Match>().Select((m, index) => new{ Index = index, Match = m }),
            x => x.Index,
            x => x.Index,
            (x, y) => new{ StartIndex = x.Match.Index, EndIndex = y.Match.Index + y.Match.Length });
var items = dataIndices
    .Aggregate(new List<string>(), (list, x) =>
    {
        var item = text.Substring(x.StartIndex, x.EndIndex - x.StartIndex);
        list.Add(item);
        return list;
    });

var result = items.SelectMany(x => 
{
    var lines = x.Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine, "\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return lines.Skip(1) //Skip header
        .Take(lines.Length - 2) // Ignore footer
        .Select(line =>
        {
            var match = lineRegex.Match(line);
            return new
            {
                Ptc = match.Groups["PTC"].Value,
                Cur = match.Groups["Cur"].Value,
                Tax = Convert.ToDouble(match.Groups["Tax"].Value)
            };
        });
});
```